# Extracting AIC from multiple regression models

Tags: r, model-comparison

I have a few binary logistic regression models in R (over a 100). I would like to list all the individual regression models along with their AIC, Null deviance, residual deviance etc. in this format

```
  Model      AIC        Null deviance
     reg1      155.13        ..
     reg2      154.     
     reg3
```

Is it possible to have a code that would achieve this for me avoiding the manual work

Thank you

Comment: Please read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. It's better if you take time to build a reproducible example. And show us your work so far.

Comment: look at the package `broom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the parameters of the model from the list of models using `sapply` function. Then aggregate these parameters in a data frame.

Please see the code below together with simulated list of models for logistic regression.

```
set.seed(123)

# simulation
# generates list of 100 models

xs <-  replicate(
  n = 100, 
  expr = {
    x <- rnorm(1000)          
    z <- 1 + 2 * x        
    pr <- 1 / (1 + exp(-z))         
    y <- rbinom(1000, 1, pr)      

    #now feed it to glm for logistic regression
    model <- glm(y ~ x, family = "binomial")
    model
  },
  simplify = FALSE
)

# list of models created
# now let's create a data frame
# extracting parameter from the models
summary(xs[[1]])
df <- data.frame(
  model = seq_along(xs),
  aic = sapply(xs, AIC),
  null_deviance = sapply(xs, function(x) x$null.deviance),
  df_residual = sapply(xs, function(x) x$df.residual)
)
head(df)
```

Output:

```
  model      aic null_deviance df_residual
1     1 867.0781      1259.696         998
2     2 853.3573      1311.370         998
3     3 904.3534      1276.693         998
4     4 922.6175      1296.127         998
5     5 884.0100      1271.172         998
6     6 878.9568      1289.871         998
```